# How to limit idle instances to 1 and continue with auto scaling when it needed - App engine standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, autoscaling, app.yaml

I want to achieve this from the app.yaml:

1. Always one instance will left open.
2. When there is a traffic it will be auto scaling with no limits.
3. When I moving the traffic to the next version, all instances of the previous version will turn off.

I tried:

```
min_instance: 1
max_idle_instance: 1
```

It worked fine (1 instance always open), but when I deploy a new version and move all the traffic to the new one - the previous version continue has 1 instance open and this is a problem for me.

I tried:

```
min_idle_instance: 1
max_idle_instance: 1
```

It opened 2 instances all the time (but it worked fine in turning off, when I moved the traffic to the next version).

Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

The app.yaml file configuration for autoscaling indicates the scaling for that app engine service deployment.

This means that you will need to either:

1. Remove the version after new version deployment
2. [Deploy to the same version](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--version) using the `--version` gcloud flag.